# iframe content disappearing randomly

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I'm trying to add a Facebook feed box for a Facebook page to a webpage. After trying to use Facebooks' guides I finally gave up, since I don't have an app ID and pasting the javascript in never gained results.

So I followed this brief tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmFShEeI5qg

Here is my end result:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fetcconsignment&width=97%&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&height=540" scrolling="yes" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:97%; height:540px; background: white; float:left; " allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

The feed box displays fine at first. Then it randomly (with no change or edit to the code) disappears. I got it to come back briefly by starting over from scratch in a new file...but shortly after it disappeared again (also with no change or edit to the code).

I have no idea why this is happening. So if anybody has any fix I'd love to hear about it. This is my first attempt trying to embed a Facebook feed box. I'm well versed in HTML & CSS, but not so much in JS so please talk to me as a child if your solution involves JS or any other programming language.

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fetcconsignment&stream=true" scrolling="yes" style="border:solid; border-color:#CE475F; overflow:hidden; width:97%; height:540px; background: white; float:right; " allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The answer was removing some of the excess information. The above code seems to work perfectly thus far!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:
1. You're logged in to Facebook
2. You're using Facebook with your personal Profile (not a Company/Page-Profile)
3. You're not using an Adblock-Script that might block the iframe